# tensorflow models compilation

Tags: build, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to try out the tensorflow models which are location in tensorflow model zoo. Since I'm not familiar with the Bazel compilation procedure, I'm somehow confused how these models should be compiled and used. Does anyone know how it's being done?

Answer (score 1):

First use `blaze build` to build a target and run the target file under `blaze-bin` directory. E.g. in the [inception model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception):

```
# Build the model. Note that we need to make sure the TensorFlow is ready to
# use before this as this command will not build TensorFlow.
bazel build inception/imagenet_train

# run it
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train --num_gpus=1 --batch_size=32 --train_dir=/tmp/imagenet_train --data_dir=/tmp/imagenet_data
```